# Change the size of ggplot2 plot in Sweave without making the text/numbers disproportionately large

Tags: r, ggplot2, sweave

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367393/how-to-control-the-dimension-size-of-a-plot-with-ggplot2) about changing the size of a ggplot2 plot in Sweave. I added the `Sweaveopts{width=3, height=3}` and it does shrink the size of the plot, but it doesn't scale down the text. So in the end, all of the numbers on the axes overlap.

Is there a way to scale the entire ggplot2 plot in Sweave so that I don't have to manually scale every component in the original ggplot2 call? It seems like something I should be able to do, but I can't find it in the ggplot2 book or on the website. Thanks!

FWIW, here's my call in Sweave:

```
\SweaveOpts{width=3, height=3}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE>>=
print(plot.m)
@
\end{center}
\caption{stuff}
\label{fig:stuff}
\end{figure}
```

And the call that generates the ggplot2 plot:

```
plot.m <- ggplot(temp, aes(date, spread)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_date(major="years", minor="months")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control the dimension / size of a plot with ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367393/how-to-control-the-dimension-size-of-a-plot-with-ggplot2)

Comment: @Dirk -- it's definitely very close. I tried the answer (I link to it in the question) and it changes the overall size of the plot, but it doesn't scale the axes, so numbers overlap. I may have to manually change all settings to do this, but I thought someone may know a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically a Sweave FAQ. Google and you will find a gazillion hits.

One approach is to just write the file to pdf (no scaling) and to then scale on the `\includegraphics` command.  I just looked at a vignette I finished a couple of days ago where I wanted something approximately as wide as the page and I did:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
  \centering
<<someLabel,fig=TRUE,width=8>>=
## some R code omitted
print(dotplot(foo ~ bar | someFactor, group=someThing, 
              data=someDF, layout=c(1,3),
              xlab="some X label", ylab="",
              key=simpleKey(text=c("A","B"), space="top")))
@
  \caption{Some caption.}
  \label{fig:someLabel}
\end{figure}
```

some basically just one width dimension at the Sweave options level.  I found that small values do not work well -- so try something bigger as eg 6 or 7 inches.

Comment: thanks! To avoid the scaling issues I printed to pdf and used \includegraphics. I was hoping there was a solution built in ggplot2, but I guess not.

Comment: Well, that is how we used to do thing pre-Sweave anway :)  And one advantage is that you can now wrap the file creation inside of `if ( ! file.exists("chart.pdf") ) ...`  so you do get some speedups.  But still odd that there is no finer control.