# R, Latex, Sweave, ggplot2 - change ggplot dimensions

Tags: r, latex, ggplot2, sweave

Cuurently I am working on a R Sweave report. And I am having some difficulties with the ggplot dimensions in the sweave pdf output. My code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo 

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
<<echo=FALSE, fig=TRUE>>=
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a= c(1:10), b = c (10:1))

ggplot(data = df, aes(a, b)) + geom_line()
@
  \caption{caption}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}

demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo 

\end{document}
```

Now I want to control the plot width and height dimensions in the pdf output. actually I want to keep the height the same but make the width as the same as the text width.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Perhaps one of these will help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3367393, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4495528, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5258901

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work for my code. I am now starting to think that I've some kind of error in my latex installation.

Comment: What didn't work?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for other advice about improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the ggsave.latex() function from the AFLP package which is available on R-Forge

```
install.packages("AFLP", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Then your Sweave file simplifies to this

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo 

<<echo=FALSE, results = tex>>=
library(ggplot2)
ggsave.latex <- AFLP:::ggsave.latex
df <- data.frame(a= c(1:10), b = c (10:1))
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(a, b)) + geom_line()
ggsave.latex(p, filename = "myplot.pdf", width = 2, height = 10, caption = "Your caption")
@

demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo 

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is what Sweave users usually do: invent their own functions or use other tricks to write LaTeX code like `\includegraphics[width=...]{}` into the document with chunk option `results=tex`. What if this chunk has other types of output? e.g. `print(lm)`. Sweave really should have added options to control dimensions of plots in the output (I waited and waited, and finally added by myself: https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme)

Comment: Knitr looks nice. for my next project I will certainly consider using knitr.

Answer (score 7):

You could try using the [`knitr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) package. (Full Disclosure: I am a minor contributor to the codebase of this package), which allows you to specify `out.width`, which controls the width of the figure. So, you could rewrite your code chunk as

```
<<echo=FALSE, out.width = '0.9\\textwidth'>>=
suppressMessages(require(ggplot2))
df <- data.frame(a= c(1:10), b = c (10:1))
ggplot(data = df, aes(a, b)) + geom_line()
@
```

Comment: This doesn't control height, right? With Sweave, we could use `\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.9\textwidth}`, but this applies to all figures, of course.

Comment: you could use `\SweaveOpts{out.width = 0.9\textwidth}` to make this global for all figures.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot, Ramnath. FWIW, I paste the complete code here:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo 

\begin{figure}[h]
<<echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', out.width='0.9\\textwidth', message=FALSE>>=
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a= c(1:10), b = c (10:1))
ggplot(data = df, aes(a, b)) + geom_line()
@
  \caption{caption}
\end{figure}

demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo demo 

\end{document}
```

I added options `fig.align='center'` to center the figure (you do not need to use `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` in LaTeX, which sometimes may center align unexpected stuff in the document), and `message=FALSE` to suppress messages from `require(ggplot2)`.

You can compile the document by:

```
library(knitr)
knit('your_document.Rnw')
```

Comment: you can also directly compile to `pdf` using `knit2pdf`.